# How to test value is inside array with awk

Tags: arrays, awk

#### my-script.awk

```
#!/env/bin awk
BEGIN {
    toggleValues="U+4E00,U+9FFF,U+3400,U+4DBF,U+20000,U+2A6DF,U+2A700,U+2B73F,U+2B740,U+2B81F,U+2B820,U+2CEAF,U+F900,U+FAFF"
    split(toggleValues, boundaries, ",")
    if ("U+4E00" in boundaries) {print "inside"}
}
```

#### Run

```
echo ''| awk -f my-script.awk
```

#### Question

Why I don't see `inside` printed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

awk stores arrays differently then what you expect. It's a key/value pair with the key (from `split()` is the integer index starting at 0 and the value is the string that was `split()` it into that element.

The `awk` `in` condition tests keys, not values. So your `"U+4E00" in boundaries` condition isn't going to pass. Instead you'll need to iterate your array and look for the value.

```
for (boundary in boundaries) { if(boundaries[boundary] == "U+4E00") { print "inside" }
```

Either that or you can create a new array based on the existing one, but with the values stored as the key so the `in` operator will work as is.

```
for (i in boundaries) {boundaries2[boundaries[i]] = ""}
if ("U+4E00" in boundaries2){print "inside"}
```

This second method is a little hackey since all your element values are set to `""`, but it's useful if you are going to iterate through large file and just want to use the `in` operator to test that a field is in your array (as opposed to iterating the array on each record, which might be more expensive).